# Regex replace text to tag html starts with character

Tags: php, regex

I need to bring a text to html tag, like this:

```
input: p1: Question 1

output: <h3>Question 1</h3>
```

or also

```
input: question 1: ¿question 1?

output: <h3>¿question 1?</h3>
```

The detail that I don't get it, I have the following Regex rule.

```
([a-zA-Z])([1-9])(:)+(.*)?
```

and my result is:

```
<h3> Question 1</h3>
question 1: ¿question 1?
```

- In the first one I need to remove the space that is generated between `<h3>` and the `Q`
- In the second it doesn't work for me at all

Could you help me in what I am failing in the regex rule?

**[DEMO](https://regexr.com/7hnrb)**

Comment: I don't see any space between the h3 and the Q in the first one

Comment: `([a-zA-Z])([1-9])` doesn't match the second input because it doesn't allow a space before the number.

Comment: if it exists https://i.imgur.com/qyW537h.png

Comment: Please show your PHP code.

Comment: Can you have 2-digit numbers? Your regexp only matches numbers from 1 to 9, not 10 or more.

Comment: @Barmar I just added the DEMO link where you can see it online

Comment: @LeninZapata https://regexr.com/7hnrk

Comment: (IMO https://regex101.com/ is a better tool than regexr)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The regexp needs to match optional whitespace before the question number (to fix the second problem) and after the `:` (to fix the first problem).

```
([a-zA-Z]+)\s*([1-9])(:)+\s*(.*)
```

[DEMO](https://regexr.com/7hns3)

There's no need for `?` after `(.*)`. Since `.*` matches a zero-length string, you don't need to mark it as optional.

I'm not really sure why you have `+` after `(:)` -- do you really want to allow something like `Question 1:::::`?

Comment: Add your expression but it doesn't work in the second case https://i.imgur.com/Yl407oq.png

Comment: Needed to add `+` to match the whole word `Question`

Answer (score 2):

You can use a single capture group, and match optional horizontal whitespace chars with `\h*`

In the capture group, match at least a single non whitespace char with `\S`

```
[a-zA-Z]+\h*[1-9]:\h*(\S.*)
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/NLWxx3/1)

In the replacement use the value of group 1:

```
<h3>$1</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

The answer was, thanks to the user @User863

```
([a-zA-Z ])+([1-9])(:)+\s*(.*)
```